# rss feed problem

Tags: php, rss

I made rss feed in php and I have 
problem.
I get error when I was getting input from the user.
The error is:

`Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\rss.php on line 52`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>RSS Feed</title>
        <style>
            h1{
                text-align: center;
                color:black;
            }
            #link
            {
                    margin: 100px 50px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
<body>
    <h1>RSS Feed</h1>

    <form method="post" name="lin">
        <a>Put link: </a><input type="text" name="link">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
            or die("It has problem with connect to mysql server");


$db = mysql_select_db("rss", $connection)
            or die("dont find some database");

$link = file_get_contents(@$_POST['link']);
$domain = strstr($link, '<a title=');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `link`";
        $result = mysql_query($query)
                or die("Query Faild!: " . mysql_error());


    if($doamin == TRUE)
        {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `link` (title) VALUES('NewMessage')";
        $result = mysql_query($query)
                or die("Query faild!: " . mysql_error());
        }
    else
        {
            return 0;
        }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        print '<div id="link"></br />';
        print $row['title'];
        print "</a>";
    }
    mysql_close($connection);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help

Comment: An INSERT query does not return an object, it returns just TRUE/FALSE. You probably need to use a different variable name to catch the INSERT query's result into, because it overwrites the results of the SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

$result is declared twice. I guess you want the first one, but if $doamin == TRUE you get the second $result, which is boolean (result of an insert), hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you get that error only when $domain is true, causing line 44 to overwrite $result with the return of a mysql_query call on an INSERT statement, which returns a boolean:

http://jp.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

This section is your problem:

```
if($domain == TRUE)
                {
                $query = "INSERT INTO `link` (title) VALUES('NewMessage')";
                $result = mysql_query($query)
                                or die("Query faild!: " . mysql_error());
                }
        else
                {
                        return 0;
                }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

You are inserting a record and expecting it to return something which it can't. You need to run a SELECT query to bring back a recordset

Answer (score 0):

Use `print mysql_error();` to find out the reason.

`$doamin` is spelled wrong. Hencewhy the `INSERT` is never executed. If it was run, then the previous `$result` would vanish and lead to the aforementioned error `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`